# How to control fan speed in Linux running HP laptop?

Tags: fan, sensors, zorin

I have Hewlett-Packard 183E (U3E1) motherboard in my HP Pavillion G6 2230TX laptop. I have 4 pinned fan (I have seen in forums, saying this as the indication of PWM controlling ability?). My BIOS has this option for fan: *Fan Always On*  I can only disable it. I am now running Zorin 12.

I have tried the steps given in the [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/46135/698819) of the question [How to control fan speed?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/22108/how-to-control-fan-speed). I am stuck, as others in the comments of that linked question with this message,

> /usr/sbin/pwmconfig: There are no pwm-capable sensor modules installed

That question has found solution for dell laptops, I have hp. What can I do to control my fan?

Comment: Why do you want to control your fan?

Comment: Thank you for the reply. My laptop's temperature is increasing to 80 degree C in one and a half hours. Fan runs, but too too slow, almost seems not running. If I wan to use it longer, I need to make it run properly.

Comment: It sounds like you should be asking “How do I get my laptop to stop running so hot?”

Comment: what's the problem with the question? if he wants to let his cpu burn, what's the problem? the question is accurate because probably he made a research and found out that the actual point is that, in his laptop, he can read the temperature, but there is no way to turn off the fan when the temperature is low.

Comment: @Scott I mean, aren't all CPUs going to run hot without fan speed scaling? It seems "how do I get my laptop to stop running so hot" is literally tackled by answering how one gets the fan to run in proportion to the CPU load (within reason; sure, if this is due to a locked up app/process, that's another story. I'm saying this would happen even on a properly running computer and improper fan control just by e.g. opening up a browser).